# How can I select integer values from an NVARCHAR column in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

I'm trying to get values of `fk_unitserial` that are integers. The column is defined as `nvarchar(255), not null`.

I *think* I'm selecting numeric values from this column and determining if those values are in a specific range using the following query:

```
select t.pkid, t.fk_unitserial
from (
    select r.pkid, r.fk_unitserial
    from tbl_ovenresults r
    where isnumeric(r.fk_unitserial + '.0e0') = 1
) t
where convert(decimal(38, 0), t.fk_unitserial) between -2147483648 and 2147483647
order by t.pkid
```

But running it gives me the message:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.
```

It *looks* like the offending value is `129896545820`, but running

```
select convert(decimal(38, 0), 129896545820)
```

works as expected.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I guess what I'm really asking, maybe, is if `ISNUMERIC` ever returns `1` for values that can't be used in `CONVERT(DECIMAL(38, 0), value)`.

Comment: The offending value is definitely not 129896545820, as I created a sample table with nvarchar column type and the mentioned value and the query ran fine. There must be some characters or spaces between the numeric values that you are missing.

Comment: @Sonam - Will `ISNUMERIC` return `1` for any values that can't be converted using my `CONVERT` method?

Comment: I don't think so, Isnumeric will definitely return 0 for the values that cant be converted in above mentioned condition.

Comment: You could try running just the inner select with the convert as a 3rd field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server reserves the right to rearrange expressions, with the exception of the `case` statement.  That means that you can have offending values passed from the subquery to the outer query.

The one exception is the `case` statement, where sequential evaluation is generally followed (there is an asterisk when it involves aggregated expression, but that is not an issue here).  I would suggest:

```
select r.pkid, r.fk_unitserial
from tbl_ovenresults r
where (case when r.fk_unitserial not like '[^0-9]' then convert(decimal(38, 0), t.fk_unitserial) end)
          between -2147483648 and 2147483647 
order by t.pkid;
```

As a note.  Your expression for `isnumeric` will return true for the value `'-'`.

Comment: Did the trick. But should the `not like` in your example be `like`?

Comment: @ken . . . No.  The expression is saying "the column is not like a pattern that doesn't contain a digit".  Okay, that doesn't make sense.  It is really saying "There are only digits in the column".